# Switch & SwitchAndroid doesn't work in Android

Tags: react-native

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Switch,
  Text,
  View
} = React;

var BasicSwitchExample = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      trueSwitchIsOn: true,
      falseSwitchIsOn: false,
    };
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Switch
          onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({falseSwitchIsOn: value})}
          style={{marginBottom: 10}}
          value={this.state.falseSwitchIsOn} />
        <Switch
          onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({trueSwitchIsOn: value})}
          value={this.state.trueSwitchIsOn} />
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

BasicSwitchExample doesn't work in Android.

[error screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTmQz.jpg)

```html
compile ('com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1'){
 exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is pretty old, but if anyone ends up here...

I had the exact same problem, after little bit of digging into source I found out that it was caused by android theme i was using.

So the solution for me was to switch android theme in `andorid/app/src/main/res/styles.xml` from `android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine on both iOS and Android. Check it [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/UpbiAg).

Your error doesn't come from the Switches code. Maybe try and reinstall react-native.

Comment: It looks like this error caused by  'onMeasure & makeLayout'.If I define 'width & height' in Switch's style,it will not throw error,however is doesn't show.